# Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1. flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am getting this error when I want to run my flutter app. 
I am using flutter 1.0.0 version and android studio 3.2.1 version.

My emulator is Pixel 2 android 8.1.

I have also used android 9 but it did not work either.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "E:\TUT\flutter\project\myfirstapp\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'.
               > jcenter.bintray.com
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'.
               > dl.google.com

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 27s
  Command: E:\TUT\flutter\project\myfirstapp\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

Comment: If you run “flutter doctor” from cli the output show it’s all right or you have some error/warnings?

Comment: no it shows no errors or warning

Comment: So use @martin-zeitler answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the project Gradle version didn't install on your machine, flutter try to download the appropriate version from google server before compile.

So

1. Ensure your computer is connected to the Internet.
2. Google restricted access to some of its services in certain countries, such as Iran, Cuba, Sudan, Syria and etc. Therefore, Make sure your system has access to google developer subdomains. (use VPN in restricted countries)
3. Or Change the project Gradel version on "android\build.gradle -> dependencies" with the installed version number

Answer (score 3):

you need to add repository `google()` to the `buildscript` `dependencies` of the root project.

the file might be `E:\TUT\flutter\project\myfirstapp\android\build.gradle`

right next to the `jcenter()` repository; which does not serve this dependency.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error until I ran it with internet connection,seemingly it downloaded necessary resources.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As shown in the picture above, you should check the  plugin version and required gradle version.

For checking plugin version :android-->build.gardle-->build
        scripts-->dependencies-->calsspath
 For cheking required gardle
        version :android-->gradle-->wrappper-->gradle-wrapper.properties